# Inherit from CSS class not included/referenced in Less file

Tags: css, less

I want to make my buttons inherit from Bootstraps `.btn-primary`. Do I have to reference or include Bootstrap's less or if I know that my bootstrap.min.css is included before my compiled less file can I just say:

```
.my-btn {

    .btn-primary;
}
```

In my HTML file:

```
....
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
<link href="compiled-less.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't include class within another class once you're working with already compiled css - that only works in less. I'm usually including whole bootstrap less to my custom less, where I alter/overwrite original bootstrap properties, add my custom stuff and compile it to one minimized css file.